# ElasticSearch Bool Query and Keyword Search

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, boolean, keyword

We are executing queries similar to the query below against our Elasticsearch instance.  The query is querying an index (Mappings are below) that contains approx 3.4 million records.  The data we are querying are strings containing encrypted words that are no more than 10,000 characters in length.  We encrypt the words we are searching for and then use this as the keyword we are searching for.  The search takes an incredibly long time (over a minute) to return results.  Any help our suggestions on tuning our index or query is appreciated.

The index mapping:

```
{
"messagewords": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "MessageId": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "Words": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "creation_date": "1649868562656",
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "uuid": "YFVbbow0R66dP3uR4hF9aQ",
            "version": {
                "created": "7060299"
            },
            "provided_name": "messagewords"
        }
    }
}
```

}

The query:

```
    {
   "from":0,
   "_source":[
      "MessageId"
   ],
   "size":10000,
   "track_total_hits":true,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "bool":{
                  "should":[
                     {
                        "query_string":{
                           "query":" ((Words:\"*nsrFHeMTTBOeIUvkMrYDoA==sr8O8Rpnxn0hOZ88Mbtu4g==pUniFgw3thZ8lXlj68jHqw==XKin211F6GVXm/QzvB+iLQ==HYzhyEJpcldxo3h8Sea+yA==SwmUP1KNAG4YqGdg/KlLdw==nsrFHeMTTBOeIUvkMrYDoA==*\"))"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try whitespace analyzer:

```
"Words": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "whitespace"}
```

together with match_phrase query:

```
"match_phrase": {"words": "nsrFHeMTTBOeIUvkMrYDoA== ... SwmUP1KNAG4YqGdg/KlLdw== nsrFHeMTTBOeIUvkMrYDoA=="}
```

Please note that you'll have to split encoded tokens with spaces for it to work.